# Proof for linear code

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

Let C + x be any coset of a binary linear code C. Prove that C ∪(C +x) is a linear code. (Hint: Show that there is closure under addition and scalar multiplication.)

Could anyone help me get started on this proof?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a (direct) sum of subspaces? If not, you have a number of cases to check out. A vector $w$ in the union is either 1) a word of $C$, or 2) of the form $w'+x$ where $w'$ is a word of $C$ and $x$ is that chosen vector giving us the coset. The first task is to show that if you take two words from the union, then their sum is also in the union. There will be three cases: A) both word of the type 1, B) both of the type 2, C) one of each.

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of a (direct) sum of subspaces. I guess I need to do the other way: such as taking two words from the union...could you show me how to get started?

Comment: In case A, the words are $w_1\in C$ and $w_2\in C$. What can you say about their sum?

Comment: will still be in C?

Comment: Correct. Because $C$ is linear and closed under addition. Now what if you add $w_1+x$ and $w_2+x$ together? Then $w_1$ and $w_2+x$?

Comment: if add $w_1+x and w_2+x $, I will get C + x? right

Comment: Hmm. $(w_1+x)+(w_2+x)=w_1+w_2+2x$ is not in $C+x$.

Comment: why do we need to add $w_1 + x$ and $w_2 + x$ ? What are we trying to achieve here?

Comment: We are trying to show that the union $C'=C\cup (C+x)$ is closed under addition. That is, if you take any two words from the union, their sum will also be in the union. The key is that $2x=0$, because addition is componentwise modulo two. Checking that the union is closed under scalar multiplication will be much easier, because the only scalars here are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: $w_1+w_2$ in C because C is linear and closed under addition. $w_1+w_2+x$ gives $w_1$+$w_2$=$w_3$ in C because of the same reason and $w_3$ + x in (C+x). $w_1+x$+$w_2+x$ = $w_1$+$w_2$+2x = $w_1$+$w_1$ since 2x=0 in binary addition. so $w_1$+$w_2$ in C...so C U (C+X) is closed under addition....0($w_1$+$w_2$)=0 in C, 0($w_1$+$w_2$+x) = 0 in C, 0($w_1$+$w_2$+2x) = 0 in C, 1($w_1$+$w_2$) = $w_1$+$w_2$ in C and 1($w_1$+$w_2$+x) = $w_1$+$w_2$+x = $w_3$+x in C+x, and 1($w_1$+$w_2$+2x) = $w_1$+$w_2$= $w_3$ in C so C U (C+x) is closed under scalar multiplication.... is this right?

Comment: Congratulations! You have verified everything required by the so called subspace criterion (from a course in linear algebra). You may also consider typing that as an answer to get more feedback from other members. Well done anyway :-)